# A better tool for SOAP and XML?

Tags: xml-parsing, osgi, jax-ws, aem, soap-client

We have a web application running on Adobe AEM 5.6.1, that calls some SOAP services on SAP. 
We have used javax.xml.ws.Service for this, but from time to time I run into problems like below, where the class loader on the AEM server can't find a class from the com.sun.xml.internal.ws library.
Once I solved a similar problem by temporarely changing class loader, but that dosn't work here.
What I would really like, is to find a better library for handlig both Soap and XML parsing. Any suggestions?

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Header
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newInstance(Proxy.java:764)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:755)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate$4.run(WSServiceDelegate.java:612)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:608)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:593)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:331)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:313)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:295)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:119)
```

Comment: What's the version of Java? This seems like this error could be resolved via "Import package" in your maven build. could you please provide your pom.xml(build configuration). Regarding your initial question, you could easily create JAX WS client using Apache CXF.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your error could be resolved by using the "Import Package" in maven build configuration, you could add the correct JAX WS lib version and the above error will go away.

However, to answer your question. CQ(AEM) and Apache CXF works very well. You have to create a OSGI client using Apache CXF framework.

Reference: 
[AEM & Apache CXF](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/creating-cxf-bundles-consume-web.html)